# Jupyter Notebook gets a 404 after login

Tags: nginx, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

After an update to my Jupyter Notebook server (4.3.0) running on an Ubuntu 14.04.3 VM, I am no longer able to access my notebooks.  I am still able to access the login page via www.mywebsite/ipython.  But, logging returns a 404 page.

Shell output:

```
[I 20:17:17.250 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /home/mywebsite
[I 20:17:17.250 NotebookApp] 0 active kernels 
[I 20:17:17.251 NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at: http://localhost:9999/ipython
[I 20:17:17.251 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[I 20:17:25.177 NotebookApp] 302 GET /ipython (127.0.0.1) 1.54ms
[I 20:17:25.241 NotebookApp] 302 GET /ipython/tree? (127.0.0.1) 2.34ms
[W 20:17:25.469 NotebookApp] 404 GET /ipythoncustom/custom.css (127.0.0.1) 14.96ms referer=http://mywebsite.com/ipython/login?next=%2Fipython%2Ftree%3F
[W 20:17:43.658 NotebookApp] 404 POST /ipythonlogin?next=%2Fipython%2Ftree%3F (127.0.0.1) 6.30ms referer=http://mywebsite.com/ipython/login?next=%2Fipython%2Ftree%3F
[W 20:17:43.724 NotebookApp] 404 GET /ipythoncustom/custom.css (127.0.0.1) 2.81ms referer=http://mywebsite.com/ipythonlogin?next=%2Fipython%2Ftree%3F
```

This is running on nginx 1.4.6:

```
upstream ipython_server {
    server 127.0.0.1:9999;
}

server {
    listen   80; 

    server_name mywebsite.com www.mywebsite.com;
    root /var/www/mywebsite/;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;


    location / { 
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
    }   

    error_page 404 /404.html;

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
          root /usr/share/nginx/www;
    }   

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
            # With php5-fpm:
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
             }   
    location /ipython {
            proxy_pass http://ipython_server;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
            proxy_set_header Origin ""; 
    }   

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the nginx configuration here:
http://nathan.vertile.com/blog/2017/12/07/run-jupyter-notebook-behind-a-nginx-reverse-proxy-subpath/